# How to hide window list in tmux status bar?

Tags: configuration, tmux

How can I remove the list of tmux windows from the status bar. In this case I want to get rid of (see lower left) `1:zsh*`.

[Screenshot of my tmux window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zxi1T.png)

I tried in .tmux.conf the following

```
set -g status-style nolist
```

but it did not work. I do not want to get rid of the whole status bar, only the list of windows.

Answer (score 3):

In `~/.tmux.conf`, add the following:

```
set -g window-status-current-format ''
set -g window-status-format ''
```

Full credit goes to [this reddit comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/tmux/comments/2h3lin/how_can_i_remove_the_window_number_from_the_tmux/ckp429t).

### Minimal tmux screens

Users may want to hide their list of open windows for many reasons, but one of them may be to completely remove, or minimise heavily, the tmux status line. I had to do this when using tmux on a VT220 (and later, VT510) display, which are CRTs that can suffer from burn-in.

In order to **only** display the current time and date in the tmux status, I set the following lines:

```
# Remove left status, set right status formatted per https://man.openbsd.org/strftime.3
set -g status-right "%H%M %d %b"
set-option -g status-left ""

# No colours in the status line
set -g status-bg black
set -g status-fg white

# No window list
set -g window-status-current-format ''
set -g window-status-format ''
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change status-format[0] to remove the entire window list section (the bit between the styles containing list=on and nolist).

Alternatively you could set all of window-status-format, window-status-current-format, window-status-separator to empty strings.

Comment: Hey, either this ```set -g status-format[0] ''``` nor this `set -g window-status-format ''`,  `set -g window-status-current-format ''` and  `set -g window-status-separator ''` did the trick. Can you provide the whole code?

Comment: I didn't say set status-format[0] to empty, I said remove the section for the window list. Are you sure you are restarting tmux entirely when changing .tmux.conf?

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to do this?